Seeking advice on hosting Experience Builder DevOps app
I've been tasked with finding a solution for hosting a custom devops XB app outside of our org's AGOL account. We currently have an org website but it's built using WordPress. We do not have organization resources in either AWS or Github, and all of our office workspace productivity is handled in Google Workspace.
I'm looking to modernize our department by moving us towards open data and greater adoption of automation scripts for our rote data work, and thus I'm tending to believe that we should invest our time and efforts into Github, and thus one option for solving this hosting problem would be to put our new XB app into a Github Page, where the app would deployed and published.
I'm just wondering if I'm overthinking this, but do I need to pay anything to Github in order to do this? Should I be looking to purchase their Github Teams tier of service, or is that unnecessary?
I'm a novice in managing scripts and repositories of data, having always just relied on local machines and local servers and our AGOL to handle all of this.

Experience Builder apps built using the SDK are simply a collection of static files, which is a perfect match for the restrictive hosting functionality GitHub Pages provides. Just make sure the app is registered with your AGOL org and you should be fine.
